# Getting empty ID when trying "auth()->user()->id"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When I try to get the authenticated user `id` in laravel using `auth()->user()->id` I am getting `Attempt to read property "id" on null`

This is my controller code:

```php
public function check(Request $request) {
    $date = $request->date;

    $appointment = Appointment::where('date', $date)
        ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
        ->first();

    if (!$appointment) {
        return redirect()
            ->to('/appointment')
            ->with('errmessage', 'Appointment time not available for this date');
    }

    $appointmentId = $appointment->id;
    $times = Time::where('appointment_id', $appointmentId)->get();

    return view('admin.appointment.index', compact('times', 'appointmentId', 'date'));
}
```

Comment: The error is clear, you are trying to get `id` from `auth()->user()` but `user()` is `null`, meaning there is no user logged in... What is the route that is accessing this ? Do you have a middleware to enforce someone must be logged in for this route ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your route, in web.php, is protected by auth middleware to ensure the user is looged in.